# localhost:4000 refuses to connect when running a release's binary. How to access error log from an elixir app started from a mix release?

Tags: elixir

I'm running into a problem with `mix release` that I'm not sure how to debug.

Here's what I'm doing:

- verify that my app is working when not using the binary that `mix release` generates by using the following:

```
MIX_ENV=prod DATABASE_URL=ecto://user:pass@localhost/test_dev SECRET_KEY_BASE=GiUj6WU9zdRp3SY+mYsuXN6j3zUEonF0MVlmYOW11EziN25peb4auU0BI12uf9xQ iex -S mix phx.server
```

- visit `localhost:4000` and it works
- stop this running server
- generate a release via:

```
MIX_ENV=prod DATABASE_URL=ecto://user:pass@localhost/test_dev SECRET_KEY_BASE=GiUj6WU9zdRp3SY+mYsuXN6j3zUEonF0MVlmYOW11EziN25peb4auU0BI12uf9xQ mix release
```

- execute the binary via:

```
_build/prod/rel/test/bin/test start
```

At this point, the binary appears to be running, but `localhost:4000` refuses to connect.

I can remote into the running elixir application via:

```
_build/prod/rel/test/bin/test remote
```

but I am unsure how to access errors to find out why the server isn't running.

Does anyone know why `localhost:4000` isn't able to connect when running the release's binary? How would I debug this?

Comment: do you have `server: true` option in your endpoint config?

Comment: Yes, that was it. I had to uncomment that part in `api/config/prod.secret.exs`

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer

Comment: this is a duplicate question, just in different context

Comment: not sure, I cannot find the original question, I guess you can leave it like this, it might help someone someday.